# Sincronizar SQL Server Express y SQL Server Enterprise

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-express, sync-framework

He investigado que no se puede replicar desde una base de datos con SQL Server Express como publicador hacia un SQL Server Enterprise, por lo que he encontrado que se puede hacer la replica por medio de Visual Studio, con una herramienta llamada Sync Framework https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/synchronization/sync-framework-2.1/ff928700(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Por lo que he entendido, cuando se generan cambios en la base de datos Express, también se ven reflejados en la base de datos Enterprise.

Mis dudas son: ¿Qué pasa cuando por alguna razón, la aplicación no se puede conectar con la base Enterprise?

¿Al momento de que la aplicación se puede volver a comunicar con la base de datos Enterprise, se hace la sincronización de los datos que no se actualizaron cuando la aplicación no se podía comunicar con el servidor Enterprise?

Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigos, acabo de encontrar una solucion en la pagina: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/06/01/database-synchronization-with-the-microsoft-sync-framework.aspx

Ahí hay un excelente tutorial en el cual nos muestran como sincronizar mediante código, además de que hay un código de ejemplo.